# Dateutil package: absolute difference in seconds between two dates

Tags: python, date, python-dateutil

I use Python and 'dateutil' package. I have two dates 'date1' and 'date2' that are parsed from some strings:

```
import dateutil.parser
date1 = dateutil.parser.parse(string1,fuzzy=True)
date2 = dateutil.parser.parse(string2,fuzzy=True)
```

How is it possible to get absolute (non-negative) time difference between 'date1' and 'date2' in seconds? Just one number.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`dateutil.parser.parse`](https://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-c0e81a473b647dfa787dc11e8c69557ec2c3ecd2) returns [`datetime.datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) objects which you can subtract from each other to get a [`datetime.timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) object, the difference between two times.

You can then use the [`total_seconds`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds) method to get the number of seconds.

```
diff = date2 - date1
print(diff.total_seconds())
```

Note that if `date1` is further in the future than `date2` then the `total_seconds` method will return a negative number.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `total_seconds()` method on a time delta:

```
import dateutil.parser
from datetime import datetime

date1 = datetime.now()
date2 = dateutil.parser.parse('2013-11-12 09:00:00',fuzzy=True)

>>> print abs((date1 - date2).total_seconds())
25711599.6705
```